# SharedPreferences not working with TextView

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a page in my application where the user can enter a product name and it's calorie count, which it then removes from a daily calorie count which comes from another class. This works perfectly I wanted to make it so that it doesn't reset to the original value each time the page is opened (unless its a fresh install / manual reset via a button).

I came across `SharedPreferences` and tried to implement this, but it always comes up with the default value in my `onResume` method and I am not too sure why and need some assistance to figure out what I am doing wrong and how to fix it, as I will need to use this in several other classes also.

My Class:

```
public class CalorieTracker extends AppCompatActivity {
protected String age, calorieCount;

protected EditText itemName, kCal;
protected TextView remainingCalories;
protected Button submitBtn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calorie_tracker);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    age = extras.getString("age");
    calorieCount = extras.getString("calories");
    System.out.println(age + ":" + calorieCount);


    itemName = findViewById(R.id.productNameCalorieTracker);
    kCal = findViewById(R.id.calorie_kcal);
    submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.submit_calorie);
    remainingCalories = findViewById(R.id.remainingCalorieCount);
    remainingCalories.setText(calorieCount);


    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int currentCount = Integer.parseInt(remainingCalories.getText().toString());
            int enteredAmount = Integer.parseInt(kCal.getText().toString());
            calorieCount = String.valueOf(currentCount - enteredAmount);
            remainingCalories.setText(calorieCount);
            SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
            editor.putString("sessionCalories",remainingCalories.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    remainingCalories.setText(mPrefs.getString("sessionCalories",""));

}
}
```

http://prntscr.com/me99dp

Image of what it looks like when I boot the application, even though the initial `calorieCount` value should be `2100` which I get from the previous page using the Bundle extras.

If I change the 
line `remainingCalories.setText(mPrefs.getString("sessionCalories",""));` in my `onResume` method, to : 
`remainingCalories.setText(mPrefs.getString("sessionCalories","3"));` then it shows 3 initially.

Comment: try `SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` and use `editor.apply()` instead of `editor.commit()`

Comment: @AntoineElMurr should I change it to `SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` in both onResume and the submitBtn?

Comment: yeah change it in both places

Comment: @AntoineElMurr still shows nothing

Comment: let me get this straight, you are entering the app and then your are putting the value inside the EditText and saving it in `sharedpreferences` and on re-opening the app you need show the saved value in the EditText ??

Comment: @AntoineElMurr yes

Comment: @JameshGong why you are setting values both in `onCreate` & on `Resume` to `remainingCalories `?

Comment: @AliAhsan I set it onCreate as I need it to have initial value at first (calorieCount) which comes from a different activity

Comment: @JameshGong Don't use `Bundle` object in the previous activity. You could save the calorie value with `SharedPredference` object in that acitivity. Also it will help you in extracting those in the next activity with no hassle. If you use `Bundle`, you will have problem if you use Ali Ahsan's answer because the if statement will always be true. So try `SharedPreference` instead of `Bundle` in the previous activity to save the calories.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your data is updated in shared preference correctly. In Activity life cycle after onviewCreated only onResume called .

so if your current activity will go to foreground or rotate then only onResume will call again.

so solution ,in button click  after set the value and get value from sharedpreference and display like this

```
 submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            //  first time save data
        setvalueFromSharedpreference()
    }
});

public setvalueFromSharedpreference()
{
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
remainingCalories.setText(mPrefs.getString("sessionCalories",""));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't display at the beginning when first opening application, always shows default value from setvalueFromSharedpreference ""

Comment: can you post your sharedpreference class?

Answer (score 0):

> when I boot the application, even though the initial calorieCount
>   value should be 2100 which I get from the previous page using the
>   Bundle extras.
>
> If I change the line
>   remainingCalories.setText(mPrefs.getString("sessionCalories","")); in
>   my onResume method, to :
>   remainingCalories.setText(mPrefs.getString("sessionCalories","3"));
>   then it shows 3 initially.

Reason editText `remainingCalories` always have default (sharedpreference value) is because `onResume` method is called after `onCreate` in activity's lifecycle. Thats why, `Bundle extras value` is being overwritten by sharedpreference value.

You can achieve this in `onCreate` method by checking if Intent extras has value. If yes, then set that value otherwise set the sharedPrefrence's value as follows

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    calorieCount = mPrefs.getString("sessionCalories",""); 

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    age = extras.getString("age");

    if(!calorieCount.isEmpty)
       remainingCalories.setText(calorieCount);
    else
    {
       calorieCount = extras.getString("calories");
    }

    System.out.println(age + ":" + calorieCount);


    itemName = findViewById(R.id.productNameCalorieTracker);
    kCal = findViewById(R.id.calorie_kcal);
    submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.submit_calorie);
    remainingCalories = findViewById(R.id.remainingCalorieCount);
    remainingCalories.setText(calorieCount);
}
```

And remove the sharedPreference setting from `onResume`.

Hope it helps cheers:)

Comment: It shows it now when first booting, but it doesn't save the value if I press submit, close app then open again.

Comment: `getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)` is private for each activity. use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)` instead

Comment: it resets the value because of the first if statement, after changing the value and saving it and I open the page again, if(extras.getString("calories") != null) is still true, so it changes the value to the original

Comment: `Else` part will executed only when you `Intent extras` is empty. Can you explain when you want to set `sharedPreferences` value?

Comment: When user first opens the page, it will have a TextView displaying a calorie count (this comes from previous activity and comes in Intent extras). The user can then enter an item name and it's kcal amount and when they press "submit" it subtracts the kcal amount of the item and gives new TextView value with updated total. So if user closes the app and re-opens, I want it to still show updated total, not the calorie count from Intent extras. Intent extras value should only show if fresh install of app

Comment: can we chat? I can explain better.

Comment: In that case, just reverse the if-else part and it should work fine.I've updated the answer